# Как перенести строку по правилам PEP8?

Tags: python, pep8

как перенести эту строку кода? просто по правилам максимум 101 символов, а тут 150

```
lines = *map("".join, field), *map("".join, zip(*field)), *map("".join, zip(*((row[index], row[-index - 1],) for index, row in enumerate(field))))
```

Comment: Используй символ \ для переноса, после чего жмякай enter.

Comment: максимум 80, но ладно

Comment: Мне больно от этой строки...

Comment: @FotonPC нет, 101, компилятор так показал, а он требует все по правилам PEP8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lines = *map("".join, field), \
        *map("".join, zip(*field)), \
        *map("".join, zip(*((row[index], row[-index - 1],)
                            for index, row in enumerate(field))))
```

Проверял с помощью [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) - ошибок не показывает.

Почему `for` так нужно форматировать - потому что здесь он часть конструкции ([generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)):

```
((row[index], row[-index - 1],) for index, row in enumerate(field))
```

И если переносить `for` на следующую строку, то он должен быть на 1 пробел правее самой левой скобки этой конструкции (не самой левой скобки предыдущей строки), таким образом как бы оставаясь внутри этой скобки (это создатели pep8 подразумевают под visual indent):

```
((row[index], row[-index - 1],)
 for index, row in enumerate(field))
```

Лайфхак: можно было вставить эту строку в PyCharm, добавить переносы строк, все отступы PyCharm сам бы правильно сделал (не всегда работает на 100% правильно, но с переносом generator expression и более простых конструкций работает).

Вообще, кроме pep8 существует Дзен Python и здравый смысл в конце концов, и лучше бы это нечитаемое нагромождение кода расписать на несколько отдельных строк без всяких извращений.

Comment: поставьте еще пробелы после запятых, по правилам PEP8 всегда так стоят пробелы, а в остальном все прошло

Comment: @Андр, поправил, еще обратите внимание на то что я добавил про PyCharm, это может сильно упростить вам жизнь.

Answer (score 3):

```
lines = *map("".join, field),\
        *map("".join, zip(*field)),\
        *map("".join, zip(*((row[index], row[-index - 1],)
            for index, row in enumerate(field))))
```

Вот так ^. Используйте слеш для переноса строк (любых).